# Electron: Maximize Window on Start

Tags: electron, desktop-application

I'm creating a electron app and am trying to allow it to open so that it is maximized on start. Is there a function of some kind that you put in the `main.js` to maximize the window? Thanks!

Comment: `win.maximize()` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`win.maximize()` will maximize your window.

One caveat: even if you instantly call this function after creating the `BrowserWindow` you may still see the small window before maximizing. So hiding the window and showing it only after maximizing should do the trick.

```js
const { BrowserWindow, app } = require("electron");

let win;
app
  .whenReady()
  .then(() => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
      show: false,
    });
    win.maximize();
    win.show();
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```